# How to locate and print one and only one entry by searching its children values

Tags: sql, oracle

This question might sound ambiguous, but please bear with me.

I have a few tables, all related to the characteristics of some properties, they are:

**property**: includes pty_id, suburb, property type and other address stuff of the property

**feature**: includes feat_id, feat_name

**property_feature**: connects property and feature

**listing**s: contains stuff like prices and availability of the property

what I am trying to achieve is, to search for the property by criteria of suburb, property type as well as the features of the property. The problem I have now is that I don't know how to find the property by **a number of features**.

I can search by suburb, one type and one feature for now. How should I construct the query if I want to search by more than one suburb or feature? I am providing my scripts for you to have a rough picture (although the work might seem rookie with bad practices):

```
SELECT  distinct P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET, P.PTY_POSTCODE,   
         P.PTY_SUBURB,P.PTY_CITY,P.P_TYPE_ID, 
         T.P_TYPE_NAME,L.SALE_PRICE, L.AVAILABILITY
FROM PROPERTY P
LEFT OUTER JOIN property_type T on P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN listings L on  P.PTY_ID = L.PTY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN property_feature R on  R.PTY_ID= P.PTY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN feature F on  R.FEAT_ID= F.FEAT_ID
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_SUBURB,'Clayton')
and f.feat_id = 43 //feature 1
and f.feat_id = 40;//feature 2
```

if using the above query, I would be getting no results. Any ideas?

## Please refer to this query for more ideas:

```
SELECT P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET, P.PTY_POSTCODE, 
       P.PTY_SUBURB,P.PTY_CITY, T.P_TYPE_NAME, 
       L.SALE_PRICE, L.AVAILABILITY, R.PTY_ID,F.FEAT_ID, 
       R.FEAT_ID,F.FEAT_NAME   
FROM PROPERTY_TYPE T, PROPERTY P, LISTINGS L, PROPERTY_FEATURE R,FEATURE F 
WHERE P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID
     AND P.PTY_ID = L.PTY_ID(+)
     AND R.FEAT_ID= F.FEAT_ID(+)
     AND R.PTY_ID= P.PTY_ID
     AND REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_SUBURB,'Nunawading');
```

this is the original structure of my query, but it gave me duplicated results (while they are actually not because they are the same entry with 2 different features). What I wanted from the query is ** given 2 features for query conditions, I get only 1 entry of this property which contains these 2 features**

so below is the data from the 2nd query:

[image: HERE]

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and desired result? You have no results because you are saying that the same field should be = 43 AND = 40

Comment: Sry I am not so familiar with the functions of this forum... not sure how to print many screenshots here. So I am gonna text thru it. Its like, this property has 2 features, a swimming pool and a lawn, I want to search this property using a where condition including these 2 features@Aleksej

Comment: Text is the best way to post data. Everyone can get your text data and build an example, while images are unuseful for this

Comment: @Aleksej Just tried to upload a screenshot.. feel free to have a look and require for more details

Answer (score 0):

You have a where condition after the `left join`... This turns it into an `inner join`. Put the condition into the join itself (`ON`...). Also, 2x possible values requires an `OR`

```
SELECT  distinct P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET, P.PTY_POSTCODE,   
         P.PTY_SUBURB,P.PTY_CITY,P.P_TYPE_ID, 
         T.P_TYPE_NAME,L.SALE_PRICE, L.AVAILABILITY
FROM PROPERTY P
LEFT OUTER JOIN property_type T on P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN listings L on  P.PTY_ID = L.PTY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN property_feature R on  R.PTY_ID= P.PTY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN feature F on  R.FEAT_ID= F.FEAT_ID
        and (f.feat_id = 43 //feature 1
        or f.feat_id = 40) //feature 2
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_SUBURB,'Clayton')
;
```

Comment: Oops I guess I overlooked something. The query actually overlook the "and" and "or" lines after the left outer join, and jumped to "where" conditions